# Why is function checkUserInput returning true for the number 56 but not for 1,21,35. I don't understand what's wrong here

Tags: solidity

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 < 0.9.0;

contract MyLoopingPracticeContract{
    uint[] longList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    uint[] numbersList = [1,21,35,56];
    //uint256 public data = numbersList.length;
    //create a function that returns true if the number input given by user exists in the numbersList array else false.
    
function checkUserInput(uint256 a) public view returns(bool){
   uint i;
   bool answer = false;
    for(i=0;i<numbersList.length;i++){
        if(numbersList[i] == a){
            answer = true;
        }
        else{
            answer = false;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

function checkEven() public view returns(uint256){
    uint j;
    uint count;
    for(j=0;j<longList.length;j++){
        if(longList[j] % 2 == 0){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
 }
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the loop will run to the end (56) even if finds a match before then.

so it will set answer to true when it matches 1, 21, 35, but then continue checking and not match 56 and set answer to false.
Every time the loop runs to the last number 56 and the answer is set based whether it matches 56. For 1, 21, 35, that will be false.

In this case, when you get a positive match, you want to break out of the loop and stop looking. And that case, it seems redundant to have an else and set answer to false in the loop.